# How to force a callback to returns the result right away in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a callback function that is async and takes some time to return the result. How can i force it to wait for the result and then go to the next line of the code.

```
var result = false

        settings.areAllTheSettingsGranted { isGranted ->
                result = isGranted as Boolean
            }
        // I don't want to come to the next line unless the value has changed.
```

I need the value of the "result" before going to the next line"

**Edit:

I have another callback function inside the "areAllTheSettingsGranted":

```
 fun checkIfLocationServicesAreEnabled(resultCallback: ResultCallback) {
        settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequestBuilder.build()).apply {
            addOnSuccessListener { resultCallback(true) }
            addOnFailureListener { resultCallback(false) }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you've tagged this as [kotlin-coroutines], I'm going to assume that you can tolerate a solution that requires coroutines.  That makes it pretty straightforward:

```
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlinx.coroutines.suspendCancellableCoroutine

...

suspend fun something() {
  ...
  val result = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    settings.areAllTheSettingsGranted { isGranted ->
      cont.resume(isGranted)
    }
  }
  ...do things with result...
}
```

Comment: now it doesn't return any results. we don't go to the next line anymore and also it doesn't return any value. we never reach "cont.resume(isGranted)"

Comment: I have another callback inside "areAllTheSettingsGranted".

Comment: We can't really guess what is this `areAllTheSettingsGranted`, what does it do and why it doesn't work correctly. Above code is an equivalent of the code in the question.

Comment: in the "areAllTheSettingsGranted " there is another callback function that checks for the location settings. this is the function:




'fun checkIfLocationServicesAreEnabled(resultCallback: ResultCallback) {
        settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequestBuilder.build()).apply {
            addOnSuccessListener { resultCallback(true) }
            addOnFailureListener { resultCallback(false) }
        }
    }'